# Accessing Jira through Apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, jira

I have set up Jira Core 7.3.0 which is running and using following settings is the server.xml:

```
<Connector  port="8080" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" connectionTimeout="20000" enableLookups="false" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" protocol="HTTP/1.1" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100" disableUploadTimeout="true" bindOnInit="false" scheme="https" proxyName="SERVERNAME" proxyPort="443"/>
<Connector  port="8081" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" connectionTimeout="20000" enableLookups="false" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" protocol="HTTP/1.1" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100" disableUploadTimeout="true" bindOnInit="false"/>
```

The use of this "version" of Jira is fully funtional and running.

As soon as I installed Apache as a Reverse Proxy Jira is not the same as before. I cannot login for the first time with an existing Administartor Account.
If I login on jira(without the apache proxy)(which suceed) and then on the apache proxied "version" of jira it works. This is very confusing.

I use following Settings for the Apache httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName SERVERNAME
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName SERVERNAME
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off
    <Proxy *>
         Require all granted
    </Proxy>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /jira http://localhost:8080/jira
    ProxyPassReverse /jira http://localhost:8080/jira
    SSLCertificateFile C:\Path\to\cert\file.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile C:\Path\to\cert\file.key
</VirtualHost>
```

How could this be?

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule doesn't pass the whole original URL.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html states:

REQUEST_URI
    The path component of the requested URI, such as "/index.html". **This notably excludes the query string** which is available as its own variable named QUERY_STRING.

The reason confusing JIRA I made bold in the above.

I used with success:
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R,L]

Answer (score 0):

This is a working and Nessus scanned config. Also, Certbot.eff.org can help with your free Let’s Encrypt SSL cert, which is part of this config.

In addition to this, change context path in Jira to /jira. Leave everything else default.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443> 
Timeout 10000
ProxyTimeout 10000
ServerName intranet.mydomain.com
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"  
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyVia off
ProxyPass /jira http://myserver.local:8080/jira
ProxyPassReverse /jira http://myserver.local:8080/jira
RewriteEngine on
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/intranet.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/intranet.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost> 
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName intranet.mydomain.com
redirect / https://intranet.mydomain.com
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyVia off
RewriteEngine on
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```